# How can I select a row if a column value is present on the main model or the relation in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

If a have a "product" model that has a field code that has a one-to-many relationship with a "variation" table that has also a code field. How can I use eloquent to select the row if code value of either table has some value.

How could I do something like this:

```
   select * from product inner join variation  on product.id = variaction.product_id where product.code = "code" or variation.code = "code".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your Product and Variation models looks like these:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';

    public function variation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Variation', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```php
class Variation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'variation';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

You can obtain the data with Eloquent like this:

```php
$code = 'code';

Product::where('code', '=', $code)  // for product table
->orWhereHas('variation', function($query) use ($code) {
    $query->where('code', '=', $code);  // for variation table
});
```